# Mysql Date Format for asp Web Site on windows server 2012

Tags: mysql, asp.net, gridview

I'm working in a web application: I must read txt files and insert that entries in a database in mysql server. I can do that, when I compile my code and run it localhost (in my PC) It works perfectly, but when I publish the web site this can't read the dates from txt files.

I got txt files in my Gridview, and I insert in the table row by row (please watch FechaEmision and FechaAutorizacion, are date fields):

```
try
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow grd_Row in this.gvwAutorizaciones.Rows)
        {
            string Comprobante = Convert.ToString(grd_Row.Cells[0].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", ""));
            string SerieComprobante = Convert.ToString(grd_Row.Cells[1].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", ""));
            string RucEmisor = Convert.ToString(grd_Row.Cells[2].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", ""));
            string RazSocEmisor = Convert.ToString(grd_Row.Cells[3].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", ""));

            var FechaEmision = DateTime.ParseExact(
                grd_Row.Cells[4].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", ""),
                "dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            var FechaAutorizacion = DateTime.ParseExact(
                grd_Row.Cells[5].Text.Remove(10, 9),
                "dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);


            string TipoEmision = Convert.ToString(grd_Row.Cells[6].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", ""));
```

.........

if I run this in my PC, works and in the database I have this:

[image]

But, when I publish the app, If I run it, I have this:
[image]

As you can see, In the server dates are not working.
I think this is for language and region configuration, but in the server I set short date like yyyy-mm-dd, just like my PC. but It doesnt work.

The diferences between my pc and server are:
PC:  windows 8.1, language: english
Server: Windows server 2012 R2 Standard, language spanish.

Please, any Idea?

Comment: ParseExact says "The format of the string representation must match the specified format exactly." Do you not have to use yyyy-mm-dd in the code?

Comment: Hi wazz. When I use the format 'yyyy-mm-dd' it's not recognized like a valid format date. I don't know why...

Comment: It might be yyyy/MM/dd. I'm not sure though. More here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings The `Notes` section at the very bottom says, "You can use the CultureInfo.CultureInfo(String, Boolean) constructor to create a CultureInfo object that does not reflect a system's customizations."